# Should all questions be actual questions?

Tags: discussion

What is the site policy on question titles that are not in the form of a question?

Comment: You mean questions about actual current problems? I ask back as I'm no native English speaker.

Comment: No: Should the title of each question ex: "Should all questions be actual questions" be a question? Over at RPG.SE the style is pretty strongly enforced.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74482/should-title-of-question-be-a-question also see this question

Answer (score 11):

I strongly recommend we should enforce "Actual questions" and one question per one post policy.

So far, almost all questions are actual questions, with few execptions like this

- [Limits of sqlite](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76/limits-of-sqlite)
- [Dynamic SQL in MySQL stored routines](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321/dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-routines)

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that the title has to be a question, if that's what's being asked.

I agree with Sandy in that each question should be literally a question. Obviously discussion will provide a few avenues for clarification, but that's not what we're discussing.

---

**However, on Meta I don't know that we need as strict a rule.** I think it's fair that there may be some meta questions that won't be literal questions. I'm not sure right now *what* that may be, but we do have "discussion" tags as a default for a reason.

Comment: I'm also of the opinion the title doesn't NEED to be a question, as long as it's descriptive of the 'actual question' (the post, which definitely should be a question...and only one per, as Sandy mentioned).